# How to get values from a Json in jquery, set text values?

Tags: c#, jquery, json

I have a data table witch i serialize into a json and then parse to my view code where i use J Query to get those values.

When i use

```
document.getElementById('Name').value = UserInfo.Name;
```

the

```
Userinfo.Name = null,
```

what am i doing wrong for not being able to read my UserInfo.

Could someone please tell me how i can get the values out of UserInfo.

Below is all my code:

C# Code:

```
public JsonResult SearchForUser(int id)
{
    string Sjson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DataTable, Formatting.Indented);

    return Json(Sjson, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);          
}
```

J Query code:

```
$.post("SearchForUser", { id: id }, function (UserInfo) {
       if (UserInfo != "") 
        {   
            document.getElementById('Name').value = UserInfo.Name;
            document.getElementById('Surname').value = UserInfo.Surname;
        }
    });
```

Json :

```
 "[   {
    "UserId": 5,
    "UserName": "JamesBond@MI6.com",
    "UserPassword": "007",
    "Name": "James",
    "RoleId": 2,
    "EmployeeId": 5,
    "Active": true,
    "Name1": "James",
    "Surname": "Bond",
    "IdNumber": "007",
    "PassportNumber": "700",
    "PhysicalAddress": "MI6",
    "PostalAddress": "MI7",
    "TelNumber": "0126659007",
    "SelNumber": "0837777007",
    "EmailAddress": "JamesBond@MI6.com",
    "Designation": "Spy",
    "DateEmployedFrom": "2013-06-19T00:00:00",
    "Active1": true   } ]"
```

Extra:
I am working with MVC razor.

Thanks in advance.

Edit still can't access values (This edits are in reply with answers)

---

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: what is the Table here?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your JSON object is an array with one item. In that case you should be accessing `UserInfo[0].Name`. Also verify that `document.getElementById('Name')` does indeed find an element.

Also, since you're using jQuery, `document.getElementById('Name') = UserInfo[0].Name` could be rewritten as `$('#Name').val(UserInfo[0].Name)`.

Comment: Thanks well UserInfo[0].Name does not return null so that's getting better but it did not return name it returned a HTMLCollection[2] ?

Comment: @Pomster: in that case it looks like `UserInfo` isn't exactly what you've posted under the "Json" heading in your question. Have you checked the developer tools for the actual request? Have you logged `UserInfo` to console? Where did you get the JSON code in your question from?

Comment: If `UserInfo` is truly what you say it is, and if `#Name` exists, [that code would work](http://jsfiddle.net/RHwZ9/). The problem is elsewhere.

Comment: If i hover over UserInfo the json looks exactly as i posted. and my editor field is as follows : @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)

Comment: @Pomster: Where are you getting `HTMLCollection[2]` from? Is that the value that is being inserted into the textbox? It would be more insteresting to see a breakpoint at the point where the textbox value is assigned; inspect both the left hand and right hand of that operation. At the next step of execution, inspect the value of the textbox; could it be that it gets set accurately, but is changed at a later point? Note that you're inspecting `info` in the screenshot, not `UserInfo`.

Comment: The value of `UserInfo[0].Name` should not be a HTML collection. Either there is an error with the line assigning the value, that you haven't shown, or there is something else changing the value that you haven't shown. As you can see from my fiddle in an earlier comment, given the circumstances you've posted, the code works as expected. The error is in circumstances that aren't revealed in the question.

Comment: My json has a " before [ and a " after ], this may affect it, as i see you jsfiddle is correct

Comment: @Pomster: If `UserInfo` is a string you do indeed need to parse it as per Thirumalai's suggestion. ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NLkLk/)) This does *not* change the fact that `UserInfo[0].Name` isn't an HTML collection. If the code you've pasted is the exact and full source of the `SearchForUser` callback, then the value of the textbox is changed somewhere else.

Comment: @Pomster: In that second screenshot, you're not inspecting `UserInfo[0].Surname` you're inspecting `Surname`! That will give you the two elements that have that ID (and by the way there should never be more than two elements). But that's just an artefact of an error in your debugging! The value of the textbox never ended up saying `HTMLCollection[2]` did it?

Comment: No it never said htmlCollection[2] that's what i saw when i inspected element and hovered over Surname

Comment: @Pomster: Well, that's entirely irrelevant. That's just because the inspector treats the hovered item as the entire statement to evaluate, thus hovering `Surname` will yield the value of the global variable `Surname` which will be the same as the element of that ID. That's not a part of your problem. You can ignore that.

Comment: @Pomster: I understand nothing from your new question. There is no `Table` in the Json object you've posted so far. You are selecting all elements that match a selector that we don't know, and iterating over that to define a local variable in that iteration that is never used. That is extremely strange and not at all related to the question you've been asking. If your original problem is fixed you should open a new question. Be sure to point out *what `obj.Table` is*, as well as *what `$(obj.Table)` yields* and *what you're trying to do*; all of which are unclear at the moment.

Comment: Same problem, this is just what iv managed to get working. i'm just trying any thing at the moment to get the information out.

Comment: @Pomster: In my previous comment, I pointed out a number of questions that need to be answered. There is no `obj.Table` in the object you've shown us. You haven't told us why you are selecting all objects based on this unknown `obj.Table` and you haven't told us what you're trying to acheive with iterating over that selection. You're telling us that you've got something working and you are looking for a shorter way. *What* is working? *What are you trying to do?*

Answer (score 0):

Use `var info=jQuery.parseJSON(UserInfo);` to parse the value and then `info.Name` will give you result

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/NAnDy/)

Like your JSON object structure [Check here](http://jsfiddle.net/NAnDy/1/)

Comment: Please see edit, this is the result after following you answer but i still can't access values.

Comment: @Pomster see the demo I have created jsfiddle look that you will have some understanding

Comment: One more think for your json structure info[0].Name will give you answer

Comment: @Pomster is it gives you the result?